# How to create a xsd schema for this soap envelope xml?

Tags: xml, soap, xsd

How I can create xsd shema for this xml doc?
I tried a lot of solutions, but nothing came of it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <e:Envelope xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <e:Header>
            <RequestInfo Type="SetConfig" Id="AB1y0WzRv42Nz4G8V+UW">
                <ReturnAddresses>
                    <Address>
                        mars@contact
                    </Address>
                </ReturnAddresses>
            </RequestInfo>
        </e:Header>
        <e:Body>
            <RequestData>
                MIIBhzCCAYOgAwIBADCCAXowfDB6M
            </RequestData>
        </e:Body>
    </e:Envelope>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, what are you stuck at? Normally you would have to create a wsdl and map parts of the input message to the header when binding to soap. Parts refer to xsd element definitions (jn doc-style)

Answer (score 1):

In case you are looking for a wsdl (has been many years since i wrote one, but i believe this would be a good starting point for you)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="urn:sample/service"
                  xmlns:tns="urn:sample/service" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  xmlns:types="urn:sample/types">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema targetNamespace="urn:sample/types" elementFormDefault="qualified"
                   xmlns:tns="urn:sample/types">
            <xs:simpleType name="TSimpleEmail">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
                    <xs:pattern value="[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:complexType name="TRequestInfo">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="ReturnAddresses">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="Address" type="tns:TSimpleEmail"/>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>

                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute name="Type" type="xs:token"/>
                <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:token"/>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="RequestInfo" type="tns:TRequestInfo"/>
            <xs:element name="RequestData" type="xs:token"/>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="SampleRequestMsg">
        <wsdl:part name="p0" element="types:RequestData"/>

    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="SampleRequestHeader">
        <wsdl:part name="p0" element="types:RequestInfo"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="SamplePortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="some-sample-operation">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:SampleRequestMsg"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="SampleSOAPBinding" type="tns:SamplePortType"
                  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="some-sample-operation">
            <soap:operation soapAction="sample"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:header message="tns:SampleRequestHeader" part="p0" use="literal"/>
                <soap:body parts="p0" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>

        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="SampleService">
        <wsdl:port name="SamplePort" binding="tns:SampleSOAPBinding">
            <soap:address xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" location="none"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Notice how the header and body are mapped in the SOAP binding.

If you are looking for the XSD only, just extract only that part

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="urn:sample/types" elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:tns="urn:sample/types">
    <xs:simpleType name="TSimpleEmail">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:complexType name="TRequestInfo">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ReturnAddresses">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Address" type="tns:TSimpleEmail"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>

        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="Type" type="xs:token"/>
        <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:token"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="RequestInfo" type="tns:TRequestInfo"/>
    <xs:element name="RequestData" type="xs:token"/>
</xs:schema>
```

A sample request generated with soapUI

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="urn:sample/types">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <typ:RequestInfo Type="?" Id="?">
            <typ:ReturnAddresses>
                <typ:Address>?</typ:Address>
            </typ:ReturnAddresses>
        </typ:RequestInfo>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <typ:RequestData>?</typ:RequestData>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```